# Oddities when mixing Zend Framework 1.11 & Doctrine 2 Autoloaders

Tags: zend-framework, autoload, doctrine-orm

I have setup autoloading in my ZF/Doctrine2 app as follows

```
$zendAutoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$autoloader = array(new ClassLoader('Symfony'), 'loadClass');
$zendAutoloader->pushAutoloader($autoloader, 'Symfony');
$autoloader = array(new ClassLoader('Doctrine'), 'loadClass');
$zendAutoloader->pushAutoloader($autoloader, 'Doctrine');
$autoloader = array(new ClassLoader('Application', realpath(__DIR__ . '/..')), 'loadClass');
$zendAutoloader->pushAutoloader($autoloader, 'Application');

$autoloader = array(new ClassLoader('DoctrineExtensions'), 'loadClass');
$zendAutoloader->pushAutoloader($autoloader, 'DoctrineExtensions');
```

I find that the `DoctrineExtensions` autoloading is not working while other classes are ... to verify that the path etc are right, I tried

```
$autoloader = new ClassLoader('DoctrineExtensions');
$autoloader->register();
```

And it works. So it seems it has something to do with Zend Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well the "Doctrine" only autoloader probably already matches for the DoctrineExtensions classes. You have to reorder them accordingly.

Comment: thanks that does the trick. thats abit weird that `DoctrineExtensions` can get mixed up with `Doctrine` They start with the same thing but they are different words. I was expecting them to match `Doctrine\xxx` and `DoctrineExtensions\xxx`